# Calculando Series em Python

Tags: python-2.7

Como calcular series em Python? Criei um algoritmo mas não estou conseguindo chegar ao objetivo final.

Ex:

```
S1 = x + (x-1) + (x – 2) + ... + (x – n) 
S2 = 1  + 1 +1 + 1 +2 + … 1
```

Entrei com um número inicial e outro final, mas o resultado esta dando erro. 
Meu código:

```
while True:
    try: 
        value1 = int(input("Digite o número inicial: "))
        value2 = int(input("Digite o numero final: "))
        for i in range(value1,value2):
            num1 = value1 +(value1-1)+(value1-2)+(value1 - value2)
            i += 1
            print("Valor é: ",num1)
            break
        break
    except ValueError: 
        print("Obs: Somente números inteiros! Tente novamente...\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

A primeira série:

```
S1 = x + (x-1) + (x – 2) + ... + (x – n)
```

Pode ser simplificada para que o cálculo seja O(1) agrupando os termos em comum:

```
S1 = x + (x-1) + (x – 2) + ... + (x – n) 
   = (x + x + x + ... + x) - (0 + 1 + 2 + ... + n)
   = (n+1)*x - n*(n+1)/2
   = (n+1)*(x - n/2)
```

Ou seja, o resultado pode ser obtido apenas com algumas operações matemáticas, 4, precisamente, independente da grandeza de `n`,  sem ter que implementar algum laço de repetição que deixaria a solução, no mínimo, O(n).

Em Python, isso poderia ser implementado até em uma expressão lambda:

```
S1 = lambda x, n: (n+1)*(x - n/2)
```

Por exemplo, `S1(5, 3)` resultará em 14, pois:

```
S1 = 5 + (5 - 1) + (5 - 2) + (5 - 3)
   = 5 + 4 + 3 + 2
   = 14
```

A título de curiosidade, a solução com laço de repetição poderia ser:

```
S1 = lambda x, n: sum(x-i for i in range(n+1))
```

Quanto à série 2, fui incapaz de compreender a notação utilizada.

Comment: Aparentemente a S2 é `S2 = lambda x, n: (n+1)*(x +n/2)`; como se fosse a série 1 só que, no lugar de subtrair x por algo, soma-se x com esse mesmo algo

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado de início parecia, mas esse fator 1 que aparece em todos os termos gerou-me estranheza. Estou crente que seria uma fração: 1/x + 1/(x+1) + 1/(x+2) + ...

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com seu exemplo de série e utilizando as mesmas variáveis (x e n):

```
serie = 0
x = int(input("Digite o valor de x: "))
n = int(input("Digite o valor de n: "))

for i in range(1,n + 1):
    serie += x - i
    print("\nValor da serie +=", x, "-", i, "=", x - i)
    i += 1
print("\nValor da serie total =", serie)
```

Veja [funcionando no ideone](http://ideone.com/aKNZVu)

Para fazer a S2, basta inverter as subtrações para adições.

Comment: Não esta chegando no valor correto @Gabriel Ranéa Barbosa, mas sua ajuda me ajudou demais cara. O calculo deve ser feito com um valor inicial e outro final, Ex: inicia o calculo da serie no numero 2 e vai até o numero 5. Mas sua explicação esta ótima, muito obrigado.

Comment: O "x" ou o "n" seria de 2 a 5? Se for o "x" você pode pedir x1 e x2 ao usuário e fazer outro  `for ` antes desse para abranger o intervalo que desejar:  `for x in range(x1, x2) `:

Comment: Se a resposta te ajudou avalie para ajudar outros usuários também.

Comment: Ajudou sim, muito obrigado !!

Comment: Te convido a fazer o [tour] (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber mais sobre o site e como avaliar respostas, entre outras coisas ;)